# Error establishing a database connection while azure web app

Tags: wordpress, azure

We have hosted web apps in standard pricing mode of azure accounts. Apps are getting down continuously for sometimes and automatically recovers back.

This Error message " Error establishing a database connection "

The problem was occurring several times a day and becomes down for 10 to 15 minutes.

It is affecting our business critically.

Comment: Are you using the MySQL DB as a service on Azure?

Comment: ...ClearDB? Scale-up or move the database to your own VM if the pricing gets absurd.

Comment: @ juunas, yes i have using the MySQL DB. I have tried to create a new database, but the result is the same.

Comment: @evilSnobu, i try a site move to VM and DB local VM, but Apps are getting down continuously for sometimes and automatically recovers back. :(

Comment: I try to create a file PHP connection Mysql. from APPS not connect to DB. But a try to local computer connect to Mysql DB Succes..